# Divergence with uniformly elliptic coefficient

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vector-analysis, elliptic-equations

Let $A=A(x)$ be a matrix uniformly elliptic with $L^\infty$ coefficient, i.e. there exist $0<\lambda<\Lambda<+\infty$ such that
$$
\lambda |\xi|^2 \leq (A\xi, \xi)\leq \Lambda |\xi|^2
$$
for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, given $X=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is it true that 
$$
n\Lambda \leq \mbox{div}(AX)?
$$
I'm aware that, if $A=Id$ and hence $\lambda=\Lambda =1$ the equality holds true, but I'm not even able to prove if the divergence of $AX$ is bounded from below and from above by some universal constants $C_1=C_1(n,\lambda,\Lambda), C_2=C_2(n,\lambda,\Lambda)$

Comment: Isn't $\operatorname{div}(AX)=\operatorname{trace}(A)$, so just a real positive number? You can choose $\Lambda$ as big as you like and the assumption is always correct, but the result is not. So shouldn't it be a small $\lambda$ in your inequality?

Comment: I make a mistake, I didn't write that $A=A(x)$ is a matrix with coefficient $L^\infty$ functions

Comment: This still does not answer my question. It can happen, that $x\mapsto A(x)$ is constant. Then the calculation applies and you can still choose $\Lambda$ as big as you like. Hence I think $n\Lambda \leq \operatorname{div}(AX)$ cannot be correct in general.